# How to get the link of current directory in php?

Tags: php

I have been trying to get the current directory link and  come up with something like this as:

```
<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]paypal_success.php"; ?>
```

but really that didn't work as I got the output as :

```
http://localhost/php-login-new/invoice.phppaypal_success.php
```

so really I want to trim the invoice.php from it so if you can guide me please how I can do that..it will be great..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `dirname()`

```
<?php
    echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]".dirname($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])."/paypal_success.php";
?>
```

Comment: `dirname` doesn't return a string with a trailing `/`, so you probably want `"/paypal_success.php"` there.

Comment: @iPao : can you clarify please what Mark Reed has pointed out?

Answer (score 0):

$path = test/invoice.phppaypal_success.php
you should use basename($path), result is invoice.phppaypal_success.php

or you can use basename($path,".html"), result is invoice.phppaypal_success

$result_path = basename($path)
then you can use substr() in php

echo substr($result_path,5,-22);

Maybe this can help you

Comment: Thanks for your help but I want to ignore the invoice.php and straight ahead I get link as : `http://localhost/php-login-new/paypal_success.php`